Does customize compiling the Flutter engine with release mode on the Windows platform work?
I want to compile the Flutter engine with release mode on the Windows platform. But refer to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/docs/engine/contributing/Compiling-the-engine.md#compiling-for-windows:%7E:text=If:~:text=Release%20and%20profile%20are%20not%20yet%20supported%20for%20the%20desktop%20shell, I can't understand this sentence "Release and profile are not yet supported for the desktop shell." Does it mean customizing The flutter Engine only work for debug mode?
Is there any advise for that?
